# Firebase join data in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm try to join three data using Firebase. I want to retrieve the the `school name` querying to `classes` data knowing only guard key which is `g1`. I know it can be done in two separate calls, but I'm trying to do it in just one call to the server.

Is it somewhat possible?

**Schools**

```
schools : 
  schoolKey1 :
    name: School One
  schoolKey2 :
    name: School Two
```

**Classes**

```
classes : 
  someKey1 :
    name: Class One
    school : schoolKey1
    guard : g1
```

**Guard**

```
guards : 
  g1 :
    name: Pipoy Pat
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be too late but you would need to follow the documentation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/structuring-data.html).

something like:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/");

    // fetch classes
    ref.child("classes").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        //get school key 
        String schoolKey = snapshot.getKey();

        //get school name from key 
        ref.child("schools/" + schoolKey + "/name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println("The school name is " + snapshot.getValue());
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            // ignore for now 
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: This works, but it's not realtime - changes are not detected. Do you know about better solution?

Comment: I am trying to do a join in another way but its not working please see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259345/combining-two-arrays-of-model-class-type-firebase-android