# Firebase Android addListenerForSingleValueEvent sometimes not returning data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When my application starts, I check the current user's details in my Firebase database (I'm storing it's uid for that).

I'm attaching addListenerForSingleValueEvent to user's ref to read it's data.

My problem is that sometimes, it doesn't return any value, neither success nor failure.

Only clearing application's data solves it, but of course forces the user to login again.

I've read some posts at SO, but didn't find any solution.

Here's my piece of code:

```
DatabaseReference newUser =    
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/"+uid);
newUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()     
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: Quick question: are you using authentication? Are you accessing multiple databases in the same app (or have you previously used the same app to access a different database)?

Comment: Yes I'm using authentication. I'm only access one database. BTW, even restarting the device didn't solve it.

Comment: That problem has started only after I've start using the new SDK.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem always in combination with the solution of this Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670234/firebase-join-data-in-android?rq=1

So if I create a Value listener, which contains a single value listener, the single value listener never returns any data so everything freezes.

Any solutions for this @FrankvanPuffelen? Do I do something wrong? Open Source project to reproduce, on PM if you like.

Comment: I had the same problem today, I temporary fixed it by doing a logout of the current user, even when I deleted it from the database it was still available in the app

Comment: I too had this problem. Call the firebase.authWithCustomToken BEFORE firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Answer (score 5):

The recommendation I've seen for this is to call `keepSynced(true)` on the `Query` object.

Comment: I have same issue with addListenerForSingleValueEvent, is that first time when application was launch, its call properly but next time when i come back on application, its not call any override method. i tried keepsynced and its work now.

Comment: but fact is there are issue with New SDK

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this.
If you can't solver by this, send share me source code for this part.
...

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            final HashMap<String, Object> dataMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            for (String key : dataMap.keySet()){
                Object data = dataMap.get(key);
                try{
                    HashMap<String, Object> moneyData = (HashMap<String, Object>) data;
                    Money money = new Money(("", "");
                }catch (ClassCastException cce){
                    try{
                        name = String.valueOf(dataMap.get("username"));
                        email = String.valueOf(dataMap.get("useremail"));
                    }catch (ClassCastException cce2){
                    }
                }
            }                            
        // do something
        }else {
        // when empty data
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `user/:id` does not exist. Double-check your error output:

```
DatabaseReference newUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference("users")
    .child(uid)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()     
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Log.i(TAG, snapshot.val());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Not found: " + uid);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, databaseError.toString();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I've been having the same problem for days and I finally fixed it.

Looks like my Api key was changed! And that's what was preventing `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` from returning!
Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), open your project, click the settings icon [image: gear icon] and go to **Project settings**. There you'll see `Web API Key`. Take that and copy it to your `google-services.json` file in your project's directory. Here's a snippet from that file:

```
  ...
  ],
  "api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": "<COPY Web Api Key HERE>"
    }
  ],
  ...
```

That's it. After replacing the value of "current_key" with the key from Firebase, it returned to work (previously it had some other key I think I generated at [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and it worked for months. Just a few days ago it stopped working)