# Issue while retrieving data from firebase second time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While trying to retrieve data from firebase for the second time , it does not go inside the onChildAdded method and gives empty result. It works fine for the first time.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    Query quesry = databaseReference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(name);
    quesry.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
```

Comment: It appears that your `Query` is looking for a child with a specific "name"  that is being added. Are you really looking for only that "name"  that is being added or do you really want `onDataChange` instead?

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703218/firebase-android-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent-sometimes-not-returning-data/40114759#40114759

Comment: @Barns Yes, I have child with &#39;name&#39; if value matches, I want all the other children as well. 
Structure is like :
Users:
  First:
     name:&quot;Abc&quot;
     status:&quot;Offline&quot;

Comment: @Barns `ChildEventListener.onChildAdded` will initially fire for each existing child that matches the query. There is no need to use a `ValueEventListener.onDataChange` for that.

Comment: @Rishabh What is "for the first time" and "for the second time"?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen :: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen basically I am populating a list based on status of users and preforming operation on it and removing each element from list. Once I remove all the elemets, I want to go back to firebase and fetch again all the Online users even though the status didn't change from the last time.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing more than what you've shown so far. Please update your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have passed name in a query. Let it be John. It retrieves the John details and set it in the list. So you are having one entry for John. ie. why only 1 item is set in the list and no second item is coming.  But if you pass that name which exists more than 1, your list will display that number of enteries